# Finding all zero sums of length m and checking for zero subsums on an abelian group (generalization of the sub sum problem?)

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, python, subset-sum, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group. We say that $G$ has property $V_n$ if for every $m > n$ and a list $L\subset G$ of $m$ elements s.t. $\sum_{g\in L}g=0$ there is a proper subset $\emptyset\neq L'\subsetneq L$ s.t. $\sum_{g\in L'}g=0$. We define $V(G)=\min\{n \mid G \text{ has property }V_n\}$.
This is part of the problem of finding an arithmetic characterization of number fields.

My current code utilizes memoization (probably badly) and takes around 6 seconds to verify $V(C_2^6)=7$. It takes more than a minute to calculate $V(G)$ for most $G$'s with $V(G)>7$.

I'm really not sure what the complexity of my code is, will share it at the bottom. I would appreciate suggestions for better algorithms, improvements of my code, new code etc. I would like to be able to calculate cases up to at least $V(G)=100$ and $|G|=1000$.

Here are some values for some abelian groups. With the notation $AB((a_1,a_2,...,a_n))$ meaning there are $n$ generators $g_1$ through $g_n$ with the relations $a_i\cdot g_i = 0$. so $AB((2, 2))$ will just be $C_2\oplus C_2$:

```
{AB((2, )): 2,
 AB((3, )): 3,   AB((2, 2)): 3,
 AB((4, )): 4,   AB((2, 2, 2)): 4,
 AB((5, )): 5,   AB((3, 3)): 5,     AB((2, 4)): 5,     AB((2, 2, 2, 2)): 5,
 AB((6, )): 6,   AB((2, 2, 4)): 6,  AB(tuple([2] * 5)): 6,
 AB((7, )): 7,   AB((4, 4)): 7,     AB((2, 6)): 7,     AB((3, 3, 3)): 7, AB((2, 2, 2, 4)): 7, AB(tuple([2] * 6)): 7,
 AB((8, )): 8,   AB((3, 6)): 8,     AB((2, 4, 4)): 8,  AB((2, 2, 6)): 8, AB(tuple([2] * 4 + [4])): 8, AB(tuple([2] * 7)): 8,
 AB((9, )): 9,   AB((2, 8)): 9,     AB((5, 5)): 9,     AB((2, 2, 4, 4)): 9, AB(tuple([3] * 4)): 9, AB((2, 2, 2, 6)): 9, AB(tuple([2] * 5 + [4])): 9, AB(tuple([2] * 8)): 9,
 AB((10, )): 10, AB((2, 2, 8)): 10, AB((4, 4, 4)): 10, AB((3, 3, 6)): 10, AB((2, 2, 2, 4, 4)): 10, AB(tuple([2] * 6 + [4])): 10, AB(tuple([2] * 9)): 10}
```

Here is my code - not adding the code for an abelian group since the implementation is kinda trivial and doesn't take any significant runtime.

```
from itertools import combinations
from multiset import Multiset
from abeliangroup import AbelianGroup, group_values
from multiset import FrozenMultiset as fms

def relevant_powerset(iterable: tuple):
    for r in range(2, len(iterable) // 2 + 1):
        for combination in combinations(iterable, r):
            yield combination

def get_similar_sums(summands: tuple, zero_sum: tuple) -> set:
    diff_tuple = tuple(Multiset(summands).difference(Multiset(zero_sum)))
    return {fms(zero_sum), fms(diff_tuple)}

def has_zero_subsum(summands: tuple, g: AbelianGroup, memo: set) -> bool:
    for s in relevant_powerset(summands):
        if sum(s, start=g.zero) == g.zero:
            memo.update(get_similar_sums(summands, s))
            return True
    return False

def memoized_group_check(g: AbelianGroup, m: int, memo: set = None, summands: tuple = None) -> bool:
    assert m > 1 and g.maximal_element_order() <= m
    if memo is None:
        memo = set()
    if summands is None:
        summands = tuple()
    if fms(summands) in memo:
        return True
    if len(summands) > 0 and sum(summands, start=g.zero) == g.zero:  # this removes about a 1/4rth of the runtime.
        memo.add(fms(summands))
        return True

    if len(summands) == m - 1:
        summands = (*summands, -sum(summands, start=g.zero))
        if summands[-1] == g.zero or g.order_map[summands[-1]] < g.order_map[summands[-2]]:
            return True
        return has_zero_subsum(summands, g, memo)

    start = 0 if len(summands) == 0 else g.order_map[summands[-1]]
    for i in range(start, len(g.non_zero_elements)):
        new_summands = (*summands, g.non_zero_elements[i], )
        if has_zero_subsum(new_summands, g, memo):
            memo.add(fms(new_summands))
            continue
        if not memoized_group_check(g, m, memo, new_summands):
            return False
    return True

def memoized_calculate_v(g: AbelianGroup, max_tries: int = 10) -> int:
    meo = g.maximal_element_order()
    memo = set()
    for m in range(meo + 1, meo + max_tries + 1):
        result = memoized_group_check(g, m, memo)
        if result:
            return m - 1

def main():
    for g in group_values.keys():
        print(f"Calculated: V({g})={memoized_calculate_v(g)}\nExpected: V({g})={group_values[g]}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I can propose an algorithm that will work for an arbitrary group.  If $Z \subseteq G$ is a multiset of elements, let $\mathcal{S}(Z)$ denote the set of sums of non-trivial submultisets of $Z$, i.e.,
$$\mathcal{S}(Z) = \left\{\sum_{y \in Y} y \mid \emptyset \ne Y \subsetneq Z \right\}.$$
Say that $Z$ is *annoying* if $0 \notin \mathcal{S}(Z)$.

I suggest that you enumerate first all annoying multisets of size 1, then all annoying multisets of size 2, then all annoying multisets of size 3, etc.  Also, for each annoying set $Z$, keep track of $\mathcal{S}(Z)$.

Note that every annoying multiset $Z'$ of size $n+1$ can be expressed in the form $Z'=Z \cup \{x\}$ where $Z$ is an annoying multiset of size $n$ and $x \in G$, for some $Z,x$.  Therefore, we can enumerate all annoying multisets of size $n+1$, as follows:

- For each annoying multiset $Z$ of size $n$:

  - For each $x \in G \setminus Z$:

    1. Set $Z' := Z \cup \{x\}$.
    2. Compute $\mathcal{S}(Z')$.
    3. If $0 \notin \mathcal{S}(Z')$, add $Z'$ to the list of annoying multisets of size $n+1$.

Notice that given $\mathcal{S}(Z)$, you can efficiently compute $\mathcal{S}(Z')$ in line 2, via the relationship

$$\mathcal{S}(Z') = \mathcal{S}(Z) \cup (x + \mathcal{S}(Z)) \cup \left\{x, \sum_{z \in Z} z\right\}.$$

So, I suggest that you store $\mathcal{S}(Z)$ and $\sum_{z \in Z} z$ alongside $Z$, in the list of annoying multisets.

Also, note that without loss of generality, we can pick any arbitrary total order $<$ on $G$, and replace the inner loop with "For each $x \in G$ such that $x>\max(Z)$:".  This will speed up the algorithm a bit further.

As an optional optimization, if $n$ is much smaller than $|G|$, you could first check that all $n$-size submultisets of $Z'$ are annoying before computing $\mathcal{S}(Z')$: if any is not annoying, then $Z'$ is surely not annoying either, so you can continue on to the next $Z'$ without computing $\mathcal{S}(Z')$.

The search terminates once you reach a size that has no annoying multisets.

Finally, once the algorithm finishes, look for the largest $n$, such that there is no annoying multiset of size $>n$ that sums to zero, and conclude that $G$ satisfies property $V_n$.  (You can of course keep track of this on the fly.)

You might be able to obtain significant constant-factor speedups by implementing in C and using optimized datastructures.

In the worst case, the running time to verify $V_n$ could be $O(\left(\!\!{|G| \choose n}\!\!\right) \cdot |G|)$.  In practice the running time will hopefully be less: we can hope that as $n$ gets larger, the number of annoying multisets will be far less than $\left(\!\!{|G| \choose n}\!\!\right)$.

---

For the specific case of $G=C_2^k$, the answer is easy to derive without needing an algorithm: we are guaranteed that $C_2^k$ satisfies property $V_{k+1}$.  Property $V_{n-1}$ amounts to asking for $n$ so that, for every $n \times k$ boolean matrix $M$, if $(1,1,\dots,1) \in \text{Ker}\, M$, then there exists another non-zero element in $\text{Ker}\, M$.  In this case, if you take $n \ge k+2$, then every $n \times k$ matrix has a kernel of dimension 2 or higher, hence has at least two different non-zero vectors.  Therefore $V_{k+1}$ is satisfied.  It is easy to show that $V_k$ is not satisfied, by an explicit construction (take the identity matrix together with the all-ones row).

I don't know whether there is some similar linear-algebraic methods that can be used to specialize for the case of $G=C_{a_1} \times \cdots \times C_{a_k}$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! it will take me a bit to code this but I'll come back here with the results when its done.